# What connector to use at corner for two beams and post?

Tags: wood, framing, roof, structural, post

[image]

I'm trying to build a shed-roof pavilion.

Specs:

1. 6x6 Posts
2. 3-ply 2x12 beams

My question is how do I connect the 3-ply beams with another beam to the post at the corner flush?

I found a Simpson connector that does this but it is ridiculously expensive at $200 a pop: https://www.strongtie.com/boltedcolumncaps_columncaps/cct_cap/p/cct

Is there any cheaper option to do the flush connection?
[image]
[image]

Comment: We really need more details, particularly about loading and spans.

Comment: I note that your link is to a T-connector, not a corner connector, I presume that's just a link copy/paste error. Also, while $200 per corner isn't cheap, it's less expensive than a (multiple) hospital visits, should something fail...

Comment: @ChrisCudmore, Outside post to post dimension is 14'x12'. Total Live load, snowload, deadload in my area is 41psf.

2' Roof overhang.

Comment: If your roof rafters are going to run the length (that is, along the slope) of your roof, then all the weight of the roof is going to be carried by the beams at the top and bottom of the roof.  These are the ones that need to be beefy and tied in strongly to the posts; not the ones along the sides.

Comment: There are Simpson HUC connectors and DTT-Z tiebacks, but I sincerely doubt any of that would pass code check without an engineer’s stamp of approval. You need to think about preventing racking and twisting with a structure like that.